# After how long is boiled milk tea consumable?

Tags: food-safety, milk, tea, beverages

I made tea with milk in the morning and had it in the evening. Is it is safe? After how much time, does it become unconsumable?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answerable. But if you feel unsafe with this (or any other drink/food) simply don't consume it.

Comment: Was it refrigerated? That's a **huge** factor.

Comment: @Mong134, it wasn't refrigerated, it was left at room temp. Whats the difference?

Comment: http://www.fsis.usda.gov/FACTSheets/Danger_Zone/index.asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably not. Perishable food and drinks are considered unsafe after being in the [danger zone](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/FACTSheets/Danger_Zone/index.asp) (40°F - 140°F, 5°C - 60°C) for more than 4 hours (EDIT: when I was a cook in Massachusetts, four hours was the cut off. Apparently the USDA recommends **two** hours). And note: that's a cumulative four hours over the course of the foodstuff's lifetime, not four hours in a row. If the milk sits on the counter for an hour, then it's boiled and put into tea which then sits out for three hours, it's considered unsafe.

> Leaving food out too long at room temperature can cause bacteria (such
>   as *Staphylococcus aureus, Salmonella Enteritidis, Escherichia coli*
>   *O157:H7*, and *Campylobacter*) to grow to dangerous levels that can cause
>   illness. Bacteria grow most rapidly in the range of temperatures
>   between 40 °F and 140 °F, doubling in number in as little as 20
>   minutes. This range of temperatures is often called the "Danger Zone."
>
> **Keep Food Out of the "Danger Zone"**
>
> Never leave food out of
>   refrigeration over 2 hours. If the temperature is above 90 °F, food
>   should not be left out more than 1 hour.  Keep hot food hot — at or
>   above 140 °F. Place cooked food in chafing dishes, preheated steam
>   tables, warming trays, and/or slow cookers. Keep cold food cold — at
>   or below 40 °F. Place food in containers on ice.

Also crucial to remember when food safety is concerned: [FAT TOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT_TOM). FAT TOM is a mnemonic device which stands for:

- Food
- Acidity
- Time
- Temperature
- Oxygen
- Moisture

All of those things are a factor in the growth of bacteria. With room-temperature milky tea that's been sitting out all day, we've got the full gamut:

1. Nutrients from the milk (food)
2. If it's milky tea, it you probably didn't put lemon in it, because let's face it, that'd be gross unless you have a thing for curdled milk.
3. Time - you said it's been there since this morning
4. Temperature - at room temperature
5. Oxygen - I doubt this is space tea or that it was stored in a vacuum.
6. Moisture - it's a cup of infused water and milk. Doesn't get much more moist than that.

Remember: When in doubt, throw it out.

Comment: Good link. You might want to add some information about the danger zone in your answer in case the link ever goes away.

Comment: @JoeFish better?

Comment: quite a bit, yes. Now it's +1 worthy :)